# AWS [SES]: the reason(s) behind getting ProductionAccessNotGrantedException

Tags: amazon-ses

To use the SES within AWS to handle my site's subscriptions, I did the following:

1. Verified my email and domain that I want to send the email from. Also used IAM and gave the proper access to send a customized email
2. Using AWS Cli created a `CustomVerificationEmailTemplate`.
3. Created a configuration set and linked it to a SNS.
4. Used Java SDK, created a client of type `AmazonSimpleEmailService` and a `sendCustomVerificationEmailRequest` variable and used the `sendCustomVerificationEmail` method to send the invitation email.

However I do get the following exception:

```
[ProductionAccessNotGrantedException: null (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ProductionAccessNotGranted; Request ID: *****
```

Any idea why I do get this exception? Where should I get the production access?

Comment: Did you [request production access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html)?

Answer (score 0):

SES service will be under sandbox status by default in all AWS accounts. In sandbox status, we can not do certain things like using CustomVerificationEmailTemplate.
We need to raise a service request to take it out of sandbox status. more documentation process on how to get it out sandbox status is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html).